# Clifford modules - two definitions of the super-trace

Tags: clifford-algebras

**Definitions**

Consider a Clifford module, i.e. suppose that we are given the following data:

- An even-dimensional real vector space $V$ together with a symmetric bilinear form $Q$.
- A super-vector space $E=E^0\oplus E^1$ together with a function $V\times E\to E$ (of course this function is assumed to have some particular properties, see the comments).

Recall that the multiplication extends to a morphism
$$\gamma:\mathrm{Cl}(V,Q)\to\mathrm{End}(E)$$
of $\mathbb Z/2$-graded super-algebras. The chirality operator $\Gamma\in L(E,E)$ is defined as follows:
\begin{equation}
\forall v\in E:\Gamma v=\begin{cases}
v&\text{if }v\in E^0\\-v&\text{if }v\in E^1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Let $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ be an orthonormal basis of $V$, then $\omega\equiv e_1\cdots e_n$ is called a volume element - there are two volume elements, one for each orientation of $V$. Note that we have $\omega^2=\pm 1$ (the sign only depends on the dimension of $V$).

**Question**

For simplicity, suppose that $\omega^2=1$. Hence $\gamma(\omega)\in\mathrm{End}(E)$ is an involution and defines a decomposition $E=E^+\oplus E^-$ such that we can consider the supertrace w.r.t. to this decomposition. Another possibility is to consider the supertrace w.r.t. to the already given decomposition $E=E^0\oplus E^1$. Are they related to each other? For example, can we prove that $\Gamma=\gamma(\omega)$ for one of the two volume elements?

Comment: Not super important, but I think you're missing a condition on $\phi : V\times E \to E$, namely $\phi(v, \phi(v, e)) = Q(v)e$.

Comment: More important, should $\phi(V, E^0) \subseteq E^1$ and $\phi(V, E^1) \subseteq E^0$? And for your super-trace question are you identifying $\mathrm{Cl}(V,Q) \cong \Lambda(V)$ as vector spaces?

Comment: I also assume we are working with real vector spaces and that you meant that $Q$ is a *symmetric* bilinear form?

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff Thank you for the comments and your answer! Regarding your first comment: To be precise, I think that the Clifford relation is $$\phi(v, \phi(v, e)) = -Q(v)e,$$isn't it?

Comment: Yes, $\phi(V, E^n) \subseteq E^{n+1\mod 2}$.

Comment: "I also assume we are working with real vector spaces and that you meant that Q
 is a symmetric bilinear form?" - To be honest, I didn't specify this because I don't know whether and to what degree this makes a difference. My guess would be that it is crucial that $Q$ is symmetric, maybe it is not so important to assume an ordering on the field...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145334/discussion-between-nicholas-todoroff-and-filippo).

Answer (score 0):

No because $\omega^2 = \pm1$ but $\Gamma^2 = 1$ and $\gamma$ is an algebra morphism:
$$
  \gamma(\omega)^2 = \gamma(\omega^2) = \gamma(\pm1) = \pm\gamma(1) = \pm1.
$$
You would need to restrict $Q$ and/or the dimension of $V$ for this to be possible. I don't know what a "spinor module" is, but this can't change the dependence on $Q$ and $\dim V$.

Comment: I think that there has been misunderstanding: To me it sounds like you are answering the question whether $\gamma(\omega)$ and $\Gamma$ are **equal**. As you pointed out, this can not be the case if $\omega^2=-1$. However, I was asking whether they are **proportional**, i.e. $\gamma(\omega)=\lambda\Gamma$ for some non-zero scalar $\lambda$.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should have specified what I mean by "proportional".

Comment: @Filippo that doesn't change the argument in the real case because $\lambda^2 > 0$.